# How to enable connection security for WMI firewall rules when using VAMT 2.0?

Tags: security, wmi, windows-firewall

I want to use VAMT 2.0 to install product keys and active software in remote machines. Everything works fine as long as the `ASync-In`, `DCOM-In`, and `WMI-In` Windows Firewall rules are enabled and the action is set to *Allow the connection*. However, when I try using *Allow the connection if it is secure* (regardless of the connection security option chosen) VAMT won't connect to the remote machine. I tried using `wbemtest` and the error always is “The RPC server is unavailable”, error code 0x800706ba.

How do I setup at least some level of connection security for remote WMI access for VAMT to work? I googled for correct VAMT setup, read the [Volume Activation 2.0 Step-by-Step](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDQQFjAC&url=http://download.microsoft.com/download/c/3/8/c3815ed7-aee7-4435-802b-8e855d549154/volumeactivation2.0step-by-stepguide.doc&ei=MCnOTr-oIKXf4QT1ovkm&usg=AFQjCNEA6K9jnozS6mVIVxQGR5xNSdtMQA) guide, but no luck finding anything about connection security.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of messing with the IPSEC rules on the firewalls, why don't you just alter the scope of the rules so that DCOM-in, ASYNC-in, and WMI-in are only allowed from your workstation's IP address. That should considerably cut down the risk.

Comment: That's what I considered as an alternative. I don't have a clue how connection security settings work in Windows Firewall so that's why I'm asking how to secure the connection at the first place :-)